# Where do SQLAlchemy after_create events get their session context from?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a schema_version table in the database that needs to get populated with the current schema version at the time the database tables are created.  However, I'm having trouble using an after_create event to populate the table:

```py
    class Version(BASE):
        """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        Stores schema version in the database                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        """
        
        __tablename__ = "schema_version"

        # Attributes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        version = S.Column(S.Integer, default=schema_version, primary_key=True)

    @event.listens_for(Version.__table__, 'after_create')
    def create_version(*args, **kwargs):
        db.session.add(Version(version=schema_version))
        db.session.commit()
```

... and what I get from this is:

```
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

Which makes sense, because it's not.  My question is, what should I replace it with?  How does the connection object get passed to the event by `BASE.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` which is ultimately what triggered the event?

Also, should I actually be putting a commit() in there?  All the examples have one, but won't the data get committed with the schema build?

Comment: Looking at [documentation for `after_create`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents.after_create), the function has the signature of `(target, connection, **kw)` so if your `create_version` is modified to that, the `connection` object will be what you expected. As for how does it gets passed? [This might be the relevant code section](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/6a496a5f40efe6d58b09eeca9320829789ceaa54/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py#L885-L891).

Comment: You may also wish to reference [this piece of documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.begin) about nested begin/commit.

Comment: @metatoaster wanna post that as an answer?  It gave me enough info to figure things out.

Comment: As metatoaster hinted, if your tables are being created inside a transaction and you issue a commit, there could be problems if the connection rolls back on a subsequent error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the [documentation for `after_create`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents.after_create), it points out that the function should have the signature of `(target, connection, **kw)`.  Thus, if the `create_version` is modified to match, i.e.

```
def create_version(target, connection, **kwargs):
```

The `connection` argument should now be assigned the expected object.  As for how that is done, [this relevant code section](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/6a496a5f40efe6d58b09eeca9320829789ceaa54/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py#L885-L891) shows how the event is invoked by `sqlalchemy`.

As for putting in a `.commit()` call there, it ultimately depends on whether or not a transaction is already active for that connection, and thus it may or may not do what is expected.  [This additional piece of documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.begin) talks about the `Connection.begin` method, and it contains a note about nested begin/commit, but in short, it provided this code fragment as an explanation, which I will quote:

```
trans = connection.begin()   # outermost transaction
trans2 = connection.begin()  # "nested"
trans2.commit()              # does nothing
trans.commit()               # actually commits
```

So, it doesn't necessarily "hurt" to do something like this:

```
@event.listens_for(Version.__table__, 'after_create')
def create_version(target, connection, **kwargs):
    transaction = connection.begin()
    # do something with the transaction, or the connection...
    transaction.commit()
```

Though be warned that if there is a transaction started in this connection, this commit here might end up doing nothing as a subsequent rollback may undo this work, so you will need to evaluate your use case.

Finally, the session can bind to a connection and thus deriving a session context from within the event, thus addressing how one might interface with the ORM from within.  Putting everything together, the following is a MVCE with the minimum imports to show how this might work in practice, including usage with a session as per the example code in the question:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event, Column, Integer

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

Base = declarative_base()

class Version(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'schema_version'
    version = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


@event.listens_for(Version.__table__, 'after_create')
def create_version(target, connection, **kwargs):
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    session.add(Version(version=1))
    session.commit()
    print("*** session.commit() called")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
print("*** Values in schema_version:",
    engine.execute('select * from schema_version').all())
```

Note that the above example may require `sqlalchemy>=1.4`, given [this piece of advice about joining a session into an external transaction](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites) (as the first line of `create_version` bound the connection to a new session object).  Also of interest is this comparison between [Session-level vs. Engine level transaction control](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#session-level-vs-engine-level-transaction-control).

As for the output (timestamps removed for brevity):

```
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("schema_version")
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA temp.table_info("schema_version")
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE schema_version (
        version INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (version)
)


INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00007s] ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO schema_version (version) VALUES (?)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00010s] (1,)
*** session.commit() called
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select * from schema_version
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
*** Values in schema_version: [(1,)]
```

Note how `session.commit()` in fact did nothing in this example, as no `COMMIT` statement was emitted by the engine before the print statement, but ultimately a `COMMIT` was issued some time shortly after the fact.  This tells us that the session began inside `create_version` was indeed "nested".

Comment: So it doesn't hurt to call commit(), but also there's no reason to?  Or do you call it just in case the after_create is the very last event called in the chain of object creation?

Comment: It didn't hurt, but I called it here in the example just to show how the commit did nothing, see that the print statement was structured to be after `session.commit()`, but what got emitted was in reverse order, due to the `BEGIN (implicit)`